# Do Kierkegaard and Nietzsche have similar ideas about being and becoming?

Tags: nietzsche, existentialism, kierkegaard

I have not read much of Kierkegaard's philosophy, but this quote comes in mind when comparing his philosophy to Nietzsche's in terms of being and becoming:

> “To be human, is not a fact, but a task.” -Kierkegaard

Thinking about this quote in relation to Nietzsche's notion of Being vs. Becoming, are there similarities between the two on this issue?

Comment: `can you draw similarities between the two?` sure, absolutely you **can**.  It'd be easier to answer the question if it were narrower in scope.

Comment: I specifically asked about this quote and Nietzsche's Being and Becoming. I'm not asking overall what the similarities between them are.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your question based on your comment. Feel free to edit further if I've misunderstood you.

Comment: I thought that insofar both can be labelled as "existentialist" philosophers, this trivially is the case since it is kind of the core idea of existentialism?

Comment: See [Relation to Søren Kierkegaard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_Friedrich_Nietzsche#Relation_to_S%C3%B8ren_Kierkegaard) for influence of K on Nietzsche.

Comment: [N's concept of *becoming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Becoming_(philosophy)#Nietzsche_on_becoming) is due mainly to his knowledge of ancient Greek philosophy. See Robin Small, *Being, Becoming, and Time in Nietzsche*, into Ken Gemes & John Richardson (editors), [The Oxford Handbook of Nietzsche](https://books.google.it/books?id=yZmJAAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) , Oxford University Press (2013)

Comment: See the post : [Did Nietzsche read Kierkegaard ?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/did-nietzsche-read-kierkegaard) mas well as :  James Kellenberger, [Kierkegaard and Nietzsche](https://books.google.it/books?id=QWSADAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).